# Можно ли учить Kotlin, не зная Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

Можно ли начать учить Kotlin, если абсолютно не знаком с Java? Или же стоит сначала ознакомиться с основами Java?

Comment: можете не учить. у котлина местами больше общего с js чем с java

Comment: @ArchDemon благодарю ^^

Comment: Kotlin это довольно широкая экосистема: JVM, Android, Native, JS. К последним двум Java вообще никоим боком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не учить, но при трудоустройстве 80% что будут требовать базу знаний по джаве

Comment: Трудоустройстве куда? На какую позицию? Вот сюда точно не будут: https://anywhere.epam.com/en/vacancy/lead-javascript-react-js-kotlin-developer-for-a-healthcare-company-blt6a3dbf29bcf2a24a
А есть еще Kotlin Native, где тоже не будут.